# Как начать массив в js с 1

Tags: javascript, массивы

То есть мне нужно что бы массив в js начинался не с 0, а с 1. При этом не удаляю никаких элементов.

Мне необходимо выбирать каждый 3 элемент в массиве. Как это сделать?

Comment: А где смысл? Зачем?

Comment: Вывод статей на сайте и после каждой 3 надо ставить элемент

Comment: И что мешает сейчас?

Comment: каким образом это можно сделать если массив начинается с 0? Я в js новичок

Comment: Опишите вашу проблему конкретнее (вы можете [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/660846/edit) ваше вопрос)

Comment: Мне необходимо выбирать каждый 3 элемент в массиве, как это сделать?

Comment: А в чем проблема выбирать каждый 3й элемент в массиве, который начинается с 0?

Comment: js тут не особо причем, надо говорить "я в программировании новичёк", но вообще лучше ничего такого не говорить, а в вопросе давать ту проблему которую решаете, а не ту, что появилась в процессе решения.

Comment: Не забывайте, **вопрос имеет 2 стороны**: 1-я, как все уже многократно тут заявили - **решение конкретной проблемы** топикстартера (тебе вообще не нужен массив, делай иначе). И 2-я сторона, всех тех, кто будет искать **решение для объявления массива с 1 элемента** в гугле/яндексе. И их проблемы вы не можете решить наскоком. Поэтому, призываю всех, отвечайте на поставленный вопрос, а обходные пути и альтернативные решения пишите как дополнение.

Comment: Не понимаю, зачем делать такой массив на стороне клиента, чтобы потом отправить на сервер и опять делать это на сервере? Вы либо, что-то не договариваете, либо вас - ввели в заблуждение и нужно сменить метки на `php` или что у вас там? И корректно оформить вопрос.

Answer (score 5):

Как насчет:

```js
var arr = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ];

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 3) {
    console.log(arr[i]);
}
```

Comment: По задаче надо каждый после каждого третьего выводить что-то, т.е. цикл будет по всему массиву, с условием на кратность 3

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев исходя из комментариев к вопросу: _Мне необходимо выбирать каждый 3 элемент в массиве, как это сделать?_

Comment: Второй коммент: `Вывод статей на сайте и после каждой 3 надо ставить элемент`

Answer (score 3):

В javascript **нельзя** начать массив с 1. Нулевой элемент всегда будет учитываться в свойстве `length`.

С другой стороны, можно создать массив с дыркой вместо нулевого элемента, тогда встроенные функции работы с массивами, такие как [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) и другие, будут пропускать эти элементы:

```js
var arr = [, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
arr.forEach((el, index) => console.log(`index: ${index}, element:${el}`));
console.log('length', arr.length)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for(var i = 0; i<100; i+=3){}
```

Так?

Comment: За что поставили минус?

Answer (score 0):

```
  var arr = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ];

  for(var i = 1; i < arr.length; i += 3) {
     console.log(arr[i]);
}
```